# How to protect a web application running in a Docker container by username and password?

Tags: node.js, authentication, nginx, docker

I have written a Node.js web application that gets packaged as a Docker image. I can run this image, and everything is perfectly fine.

Now I would like to show the web application so someone else, so I would like to run the Docker image on a server on the internet - but I do not want it to be publicly available to everyone. As a minimal level of protection I'd like to add that you need to enter your username and password - **without the need to change the web application or its Docker image**.

How could I do this?

One option I can think of is not to expose the Docker image at all to the public, but have a second image using e.g. Nginx, which then uses the Node.js image as upstream, but handles authentication before passing through.

Does this sound reasonable, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NGINX can add HTTP basic authentication, so it should work.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html